# Is this a validation layer bug/oversight?

Tags: vulkan

In my `VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo` I initialize viewportCount and scissorCount to 0 since I can use `vkCmdSetViewport` and `vkCmdSetScissor` during my render pass anyway. Is the validator bugged or is it trying to tell me something other than "0 is not greater than 1"?

`[ VUID-VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo-viewportCount-01216 ] Object 0: handle = 0x5610e4b1ed80, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xe99671df | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: The VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures::multiViewport feature is disabled, but pCreateInfos[0].pViewportState->viewportCount (=0) is not 1. The Vulkan spec states: If the multiple viewports feature is not enabled, viewportCount must not be greater than 1 (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo-viewportCount-01216)`

Comment: https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures.html#features-multiViewport It seems that my code is invalid, but the validator isn't showing the correct message. Maybe someone knows who I can report this to?

Answer (score 1):

If `VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VIEWPORT_WITH_COUNT` is not included, then the count must be greater than `0`.

`vkCmdSetViewport` does not change the amount of viewports in the pipeline, just the values.

Answer (score 0):

The `viewportCount` member of `VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo` is the number of active viewports to use when the pipeline is bound to the command buffer.  This can be different from the `viewportCount` used when `vkCmdSetViewport` is called.  In particular, if you want to change the active viewport after the pipeline is bound, you must specify multiple viewports in the pipeline state create info.

Comment: That's insightful but doesn't answer my question.